# Ruby RegEx issue

Tags: ruby, regex, rspec

I'm having a problem getting my RegEx to work with my Ruby script.

Here is what I'm trying to match:

```
http://my.test.website.com/{GUID}/{GUID}/
```

Here is the RegEx that I've tested and should be matching the string as shown above:

```
/([-a-zA-Z0-9@:%_\+.~#?&\/\/=]{2,256}\.[a-z]{2,4}\b(\/[-a-zA-Z0-9@:%_\+.~#?&\/\/=]*)([\/\/[0-9a-fA-F]{8}-[0-9a-fA-F]{4}-[0-9a-fA-F]{4}-[0-9a-fA-F]{4}-[0-9a-fA-F]{12}\/\/[0-9a-fA-F]{8}-[0-9a-fA-F]{4}-[0-9a-fA-F]{4}-[0-9a-fA-F]{4}-[0-9a-fA-F]{12}\/\/])*?\/)/
```

3 capturing groups:

```
group 1: ([-a-zA-Z0-9@:%_\+.~#?&\/\/=]{2,256}\.[a-z]{2,4}\b(\/[-a-zA-Z0-9@:%_\+.~#?&\/\/=]*)([\/\/[0-9a-fA-F]{8}-[0-9a-fA-F]{4}-[0-9a-fA-F]{4}-[0-9a-fA-F]{4}-[0-9a-fA-F]{12}\/\/[0-9a-fA-F]{8}-[0-9a-fA-F]{4}-[0-9a-fA-F]{4}-[0-9a-fA-F]{4}-[0-9a-fA-F]{12}\/\/])*?\/)
group 2: (\/[-a-zA-Z0-9@:%_\+.~#?&\/\/=]*)
group 3: ([\/\/[0-9a-fA-F]{8}-[0-9a-fA-F]{4}-[0-9a-fA-F]{4}-[0-9a-fA-F]{4}-[0-9a-fA-F]{12}\/\/[0-9a-fA-F]{8}-[0-9a-fA-F]{4}-[0-9a-fA-F]{4}-[0-9a-fA-F]{4}-[0-9a-fA-F]{12}\/\/])
```

Ruby is giving me an error when trying to validate a match against this regex:

```
empty range in char class: (My RegEx goes here) (SyntaxError)
```

I appreciate any thoughts or suggestions on this.

Comment: I'm guessing Ruby doesn't like the first `-` in `...[-a-...`

Comment: @Jacob that sounds plausible. @r3nrut, try moving the `-` to the end.

Comment: I tried removing the initial dash from the alpha matches and it doesn't make any difference.  Thanks for the suggestion though.

Comment: Nope, dash is normally a range symbol when it's inside `[]`, so it has to come first in order to count as a dash (or second, immediately after `^` character class negation modifier)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have several errors in your RegEx. I am very sleepy now, so I'll just give you a hint instead of a solution:

```
...[\/\/[0-9a-fA-F]....
```

the first `[` does not belong there. Also, having `\/\/` inside `[]` is unnecessary - you only need each character once inside `[]`. Also,

```
...[-a-zA-Z0-9@:%_\+.~#?&\/\/=]{2,256}...
```

is greedy, and includes a period - indeed, includes all chars (AFAICS) that can come after it, effectively swallowing the whole string (when you get rid of other bugs). Consider `{2,256}?` instead.

Comment: You're right.  The original RegEx was horrible.  I made some changes and looked at it in a less complicated way and this is what I came up with.  So far it seems to work like I need and Ruby doesn't throw it up.  Appreciate the help.

/([-a-zA-Z0-9@:%_\+.~#?&\/\/=]+)[\/]([0-9a-fA-F]{8}-[0-9a-fA-F]{4}-[0-9a-fA-F]{4}-[0-9a-fA-F]{4}-[0-9a-fA-F]{12})[\/]([0-9a-fA-F]{8}-[0-9a-fA-F]{4}-[0-9a-fA-F]{4}-[0-9a-fA-F]{4}-[0-9a-fA-F]{12})/

Answer (score 4):

You could simplify things a bit by using [`URI`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/uri/rdoc/classes/URI.html#M009387) to deal parsing the URL, `\h` in the regex, and [`scan`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/String.html#M001181) to pull out the GUIDs:

```
uri   = URI.parse(your_url)
path  = uri.path
guids = path.scan(/\h{8}-\h{4}-\h{4}-\h{4}-\h{12}/)
```

If you need any of the non-path components of the URL the you can easily pull them out of `uri`.

You might need to tighten things up a bit depending on your data or it might be sufficient to check that `guids` has two elements.